# Firefox 29 - how do I delete history entries visited fewer than x times

Tags: firefox, history, firefox-profile, places.sqlite

### Context:

I've been using my Firefox profile for a couple of years now. My history file has become huge, naturally. I got Firefox Sync set up between my main desktop PC and my laptop.

HW configs:

- PC: i5-3450, 8 GB DDR3 RAM, Crucial M4 128 GB SSD
- laptop: Pentium SU4100, 4 GB DDR3 RAM, WD 5400 rpm HDD

Accessing history entries when typing into the Awesome Bar on my desktop takes quite a long time despite the decent config, the laptop is even slower. The experience is quite unresponsive.

I figured if I cleared the history up a little bit, I might avoid creating a new profile to speed things up.

### The question itself:

To illustrate:

[image: history]

Is there a way to delete all history entries that have been visited fewer than x (let's say 5) times and at the same time the recent visit is fewer than y (let's say 120) days old?

afaik the history file is some kind of SQL database, but I'm not really sure how the data is saved, if there's a "safe way" to edit it and what the query to do what I need would look like.

---

I kept browsing through previous SuperUser questions to see if I could find relevant information.

> In my Firefox profile directory, there is a file named `places.sqlite`. Opening it with sqlite reveals (among others) the tables `moz_places` and `moz_historyvisits`. It seems that `moz_historyvisits` uses the primary of `moz_places` to refer to the URLs.

As I'm unfamiliar with databases, I don't really understand the way the two tables mentioned in the quote are related.

screenshot of a part of the tables
[image: places_sqlite]

I've noticed the `visit_count` is in a standard format, making it easy to work with. The `last_visit_date` looks encrypted to my naked eye, but I can't see in which way.

Hope that helps, I'm at my wits' end.

Comment: To answer one of your questions, according [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/64477/how-to-remove-large-number-of-entries-from-url-history-in-firefox?rq=1), Firefox does in fact use SQL. I recommend firing up SQLLite and go from there.

Comment: What did you try so far? Before you proceed, can you confirm that a brand new Firefox profile does provide a snappier experience, especially on the laptop?

Comment: I've just posted an answer that contains some new information. As for the snappiness, no, I haven't tried, but I distinctly remember the Awesome Bar was much snappier when the profile was quite new (and the history uncluttered by some many entries), both on the laptop and the desktop.

Comment: So did you see any performance improvement after clearing your history? -- edit: oops: I see now that you've commented on the selected answer and you did noticed great improvement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With some research (see at end for 'references'), I've come up with this (kind of) simple solution:

---

**BACKUP FIRST.** 
**CLOSE FIREFOX FIRST**

---

This requires you to edit the [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) Database (a self-contained SQL database; see [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite)) of Mozilla Firefox by making a query to find all records that satisfy the condition (in your case - viewed less than 5 times ***and*** not visited in the last 120 days).

---

**BACKUP FIRST.**
**CLOSE FIREFOX FIRST**

*Instructions start:*

---

This works (tested and working with my Firefox v. 29.0.1). In 12 easy(ish) steps:

1. Install [SQLite Database Browser](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/)
2. Open it
3. Click Open Database
4. Navigate to `C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[PROFILE]` editing as required

   **BACKUP THE FOLLOWING FILE *FIRST*!!**
5. Open `places.sqlite` from the directory you opened in step 4.

   **SERIOUSLY, *BACKUP* FIRST!!**
6. Click the Execute SQL tab.
7. Enter this:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM moz_places
   WHERE
       last_visit_date BETWEEN strftime('%s','2014-04-01')*1000000
                       AND strftime('%s','2014-05-30')*1000000
       AND visit_count < x(2)
   ```
8. Replace `x(2)` to 5 (in your example)
9. Replace `2014-04-01` and `2014-05-30` with the range of dates you want
10. Press the blue play button.
11. Check if the sites displayed are correct (they should be, but double check!)
12. If they are, then replace the first two lines of the above code with:

    ```
    DELETE
    FROM moz_places
    ```

    so your code looks something like:

    ```
    DELETE
    FROM moz_places
    WHERE
        last_visit_date BETWEEN strftime('%s','2014-04-01')*1000000
                        AND strftime('%s','2014-05-30')*1000000
        AND visit_count < x(2)
    ```

DONE! Close the program and click save when closing.

*Instructions end*

---

***What about the `last_visit_date`?***

> The last_visit_date looks encrypted to my naked eye, but I can't see in which way.

I wouldn't call it 'encrypted' (although I don't disagree that it looks encrypted). It's just in another 'system'. The date is in the `Unix` time system (or `Epoch` / `POSIX`). It's the number of seconds that have passed since 00:00:00 (UTC) 1st January 1970. 1 hour is 3600 seconds. 1 year is 31556926 days.

For more info. check [this Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) article out, or [this](http://www.epochconverter.com/) website that converts time to and from epoch time.

---

Screenshots (ignore the SQL queries on these images, they are wrong. These are to tell you mostly where to be looking)

[image: SQLite Database Browser]
[image: SQLite Database Browser]
[image: SQLite Database Browser]

Thanks to ;):

- [How to write an SQL query for SQLite Manager for Firefox places.sqlite?](https://superuser.com/questions/515090/how-to-write-an-sql-query-for-sqlite-manager-for-firefox-places-sqlite)
- [need help pulling up history on specific date](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/835204) (Firefox support forum)
- [SQL DELETE Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp) (w3schools)
- [How do I decode the Last_Date_ Visited field in the places.sqlite db?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/972178) (Firefox support forum)

Comment: For added security, you might want to make a copy (backup) of the database before doing this.

Comment: Also, if you want to do this properly, you should also delete from `moz_places` any entries that no longer have a corresponding `place_id`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant delete from `moz_historyvisits`

Comment: @Bob And `place_id` in `moz_historyvisits` = `id` in `moz_places`?

Comment: Should be. There are two ways to handle it: 1. delete from `moz_historyvists ` first (`delete from moz_historyvisits as hv left join moz_places as p on hv.place_id = p.id where p.visit_count...`) or 2. after clearing `moz_places`, you can [delete from `moz_historyvisits` any entries that don't have the corresponding entry](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3384143). I prefer option 1 personally. Don't use it without testing; my SQL is rather rusty, and I learned with pgsql, not sqlite. You might actually be able to delete from both at once, lemme test.

Comment: Actually, looking at the [entity relationship diagram](http://people.mozilla.org/~dietrich/places-erd.png), there's quite a few more places that reference `moz_places`. It's easier to just assume that Firefox will notice those no longer exist and clean them up accordingly.

Comment: @Bob That's what I was thinking. Firefox should at least do that, I just don't know how to check... I can see in the History Viewer that there is no more history left (that I can see)

Comment: Thanks a ton! As for deleting all the invalid entries dependent on the now deleted history records, that'd probably take an extensive knowledge of how Firefox works. However, this will do. The Awesome bar is much snappier now.

Comment: I'll add that you should do these steps only after closing the browser.